# Split and print

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have tab-demlimted text file with 50,000lines. I want to split the first column and print as shown in output.txt

Input.txt

```
rt|371443144|mb|MN556661.1|  2200443     A
rt|371443344|mb|MN556645.1|  2594155     A
rt|371467899|mb|MN555666.1|  2594175     A
```

output.txt

```
MN556661.1   2200443     A
MN556645.1   2594155     A
MN555666.1   2594175     A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat input.txt | awk -F\| '{print $4      $5    $6}' >> output.txt
```

Comment: I never understand why people use `cat` in such a situation?

Comment: My answer addressed his question using the tools he provided. Sure you can use just awk by itself, or perl to do the same thing.

Comment: @MarkCohen Bernhard was referring to the [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat); you can achieve the same effect with `awk -F\| '{...}' file.in >file.out`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with `cut` would be:

```
cut input.txt -d'|' -f4-5 --output-delimiter='' >> output.txt
```

By the way, you mentioned in the question that it is tab delimited, but I took the `|` here as delimiter.

Comment: This example fails on my test system :usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/([^|]+\|){3}//; s/\|//'
```

i.e. delete three groups preceded by pipes, the second substitute command removes pipe after the 4th field.